# Why is this calculation of $ \lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{\mathrm{e}^{x}+\mathrm{e}^{2 x}+\cdots+\mathrm{e}^{n x}}{n}\right)^{\frac{e}{x}}$wrong?

Tags: limits

\begin{array}{l}
& =\lim _{x \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{e^{x}}{n} \frac{e^{n x}-1}{e^{x}-1}\right)^{\frac{e}{x}} \\
&=\operatorname{exp}\left[\lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{e}{x} \ln \left(\frac{e^{x}}{n} \frac{e^{n x}-1}{e^{x}-1}\right) \right] \\
&=\exp \left[e \lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{\ln \left(\frac{e^{x}}{n} \frac{e^{nx}-1}{e^{x}-1}\right)}{x}\right] \\
&\text { As } \quad \lim _{x \rightarrow 0} \ln \left(\frac{e^{x}}{n} \frac{e^{n x}-1}{e^{x}-1}\right)=\lim _{x \rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{1}{n} \frac{n e^{n x}}{e^{x}}\right) 
=1 \\
&\text { But } \quad \lim _{x \rightarrow 0} x=0
\end{array}

So the result is infinity. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You forgot the logarithm in line 3.

Comment: Sorry for the editing multiple times

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Is that correct now?

Comment: You forgot the $\ln$ after the first equality in the line starting with "As". It will be $\ln 1=0$. So it is the $0/0$ form which does not tell you much.

Comment: Like Gary said, it is in the form $0/0$, so you can try to use L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: Thanks, that's the point @Gary

Comment: $\lim A/B = \frac{\lim A}{\lim B}$ requires that both limits on the right exist and the limit in the denominator is not $0$.  You have $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}x = 0$ in your denominator, so you will have to use some other angle of attack.

Answer (score 1):

In this answer, we are going to use the following notable limits:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}(1+\alpha\cdot x)^{\frac{\beta}{x}} = e^{\alpha\cdot \beta} \;\;(1)\;\;\; \text{and}\;\;\; \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{\gamma\cdot x}-1}{\gamma \cdot x}=1\;\; (2)$$

So, we start rewrinting the your limit, in order to apply $(2)$. We can sum $n$ times $-1$ on the numerator, having:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left[\frac{(e^x-1)+(e^{2\cdot x}-1)+\dots+(e^{n\cdot x}-1)+n}{n}\right]^{\frac{e}{x}}$$

Now, because $e^{n\cdot x}-1 \; \sim \; n\cdot x$ when $x \to 0$, we have:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left[\frac{(e^x-1)+(e^{2\cdot x}-1)+\dots+(e^{n\cdot x}-1)+n}{n}\right]^{\frac{e}{x}}\; \; \sim \;\; \lim_{x\to 0}\left[\frac{x+2\cdot x+\dots+n\cdot x+n}{n}\right]^\frac{e}{x}$$

Picking up $x$ and using the fact that $1+2+\dots +(n-1)+n=\frac{n}{2}\cdot(n+1)$, we obtain:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left[\frac{x+2\cdot x+\dots+n\cdot x+n}{n}\right]^\frac{e}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\left[\frac{x\cdot\frac{n}{2}\cdot (n+1)+n}{n}\right]^{\frac{e}{x}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\left[x\cdot \frac{n+1}{2}+1\right]^\frac{e}{x}$$

Finally, we can use the notable limit $(1)$, where $\alpha=\frac{n+1}{2}$ and $\beta=e$. We have:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\left[x\cdot \frac{n+1}{2}+1\right]^\frac{e}{x}=e^{\frac{1}{2}\cdot (n+1)\cdot e}$$

This result is the same as that @Claude Leibovici obtained in his answer:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}a_n= \lim_{x\to0}e^{\frac{1}{2} e (n+1)}\left(1+\frac{1}{24} e \left(n^2-1\right) x+O\left(x^2\right) \right)=e^{\frac{1}{2}\cdot (n+1)\cdot e}$$
because:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}O(x^2)=0\;\;\; \text{and}\;\;\; \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{1}{24}\cdot e\cdot(n^2-1)\cdot x=0$$

Comment: @mingzi xingshi: if this answer has been useful, let me know smashing that +1 or accepted answer buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$a_n=\Bigg[\frac{e^x \left(e^{n x}-1\right)}{n \left(e^x-1\right)}\Bigg]^{\frac e x}\implies \log(a_n)=\frac e x \log\Bigg[\frac{e^x \left(e^{n x}-1\right)}{n \left(e^x-1\right)}\Bigg]$$
Now, use Taylor series for $x$ close to $0$
$$e^{kx}=1+k x+\frac{k^2 x^2}{2}+O\left(x^3\right)$$
$$\frac{e^x \left(e^{n x}-1\right)}{n \left(e^x-1\right)}=\frac{\left(1+ x+\frac{ x^2}{2}+O\left(x^3\right) \right) \left(1+n x+\frac{n^2 x^2}{2}+O\left(x^3\right) -1\right) }{n \left(1+ x+\frac{ x^2}{2}+O\left(x^3\right)-1 \right)}$$
$$\frac{e^x \left(e^{n x}-1\right)}{n \left(e^x-1\right)}=\frac{n x+\left(\frac{n^2}{2}+n\right) x^2+O\left(x^3\right) } {n\left(x+\frac{x^2}{2}+O\left(x^3\right)\right) }=1+\frac{1}{2} (n+1) x+O\left(x^2\right)$$
$$ \log\Bigg[\frac{e^x \left(e^{n x}-1\right)}{n \left(e^x-1\right)}\Bigg]=\frac{1}{2} (n+1) x+O\left(x^2\right)$$
$$\log(a_n)=\frac{1}{2} e (n+1)+O\left(x^1\right)$$
$$a_n=e^{\log(a_n)}=e^{\frac{1}{2} e (n+1)}+O\left(x^1\right)$$

Using one more term in the expansions, you would find
$$a_n=e^{\frac{1}{2} e (n+1)}\left(1+\frac{1}{24} e \left(n^2-1\right) x+O\left(x^2\right) \right)$$

Comment: I think you made the answer too complicated , it Is general problem that can be solved via simplification

Comment: @RAHUL. For sure but I wanted to stay as close as possible to the very preliminary steps in the question. Cheers :-)